# asp.net authorization pass to wcf

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, forms-authentication

I have asp.net web forms application with forms authorization. WCF service application located in subdirectory of ASP.NET app. User login by forms authorization and use web page that send $.Ajax() (JQuery ) requests to WCF service. On the WCF side user is unauthorized, so I can't cotroll user's actions. How can I use ASP.NET Membership Provider by WCF service? 
Also I use webHttpBinding, aspNetCompatibilityEnabled is turned on.

I tried to use HttpContext and OperationContext, but they are both are clear (without information about autorized user).

Major target is determine user ID.

Some ways that I tried:

```
        string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser();

        IPrincipal princ = HttpContext.Current.User;

        string coll = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie];

        bool tr = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

        RequestContext context = OperationContext.Current.RequestContext;

        var message = context.RequestMessage;
        var request = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)message.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];

        string authorization = request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization];

        OperationContext op = OperationContext.Current;
        ServiceSecurityContext ssc = op.ServiceSecurityContext;
        string name = ssc.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
        //IIdentity ident = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity;



        Object obj = HttpContext.Current.Session["Result"];
```

Comment: Search WCF, membershipProvider, and RoleProvider you will find tons of answers. And generally you should not need to write codes to introduce the providers, but add a few lines of config within the ServiceModel element of the web.config file of the WCF service.